# How can I add a encrypted password protected artifactory repository as proxy in Nexus

Tags: nexus, artifactory

I have access to a Artifactory maven repository using a Artifactory encrypted password like: {DESede}encryptedPassword
When I use this password in my maven settings.xml it works fine.

But when I add this repository to Nexus as a proxy repository using this password as HTTP authentication I get the error: Failed to validate facets; 1 failure

In the log I see:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: null
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.crypto.internal.PasswordCipher.decrypt(PasswordCipher.java:100)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.crypto.internal.MavenCipherImpl.doDecrypt(MavenCipherImpl.java:69)
```

I have the feeling that Nexus cannot encrypt or decrypt the password containing characters like curly braces.

Is it possible to configure a artifactory "encrypted password" protected repository to Nexus?

Comment: Perhaps they need to be escaped yes, [like in Maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html#Tips)?

Comment: Yes I tried that, like \{DESede\}encryptedPassword and also other formats like {{DESede}encryptedPassword} and \{\{DESede\}encryptedPassword\}. But they all give the error: Failed to validate facets; 1 failure

Comment: It seems that you are using an old version of Artifactory, as the DESede password is no longer in use in the newer versions of Artifactory. 
Do you have any option to upgrade your Artifactory version to newer version? in case you are using 3.x version it doesn't have to be a major version upgrade, you can also upgrade to a newer 3.x version.

Comment: The artifactory repo is external, so I can not update it.

Comment: It looks like nexus is trying to decrypt the password, which it obviously can't given that it was encrypted by Artifactory.  Have you considered using an [api key](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Updating+Your+Profile#UpdatingYourProfile-APIKey) instead?